# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'iso3166_1Alpha2') / Trying to skip null but cannot

Tags: javascript, json

I have a global list of mountains.  I want to filter all French mountains. To do this, I need to check if `iso3166_1Alpha2` is set to FR.  The problem is that not all mountains have a value.  The script dies after it hits a null value I think because this is the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'iso3166_1Alpha2')
```

This is my script. Seems my check of `!== null` is not working and do not know why.

```
function addJSON() {
  let url = "https://development.example.com/admin/mtn/json/mtn_areas.geojson";
  fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      let mtn = data.features;
      for (var i = 0; i < mtn.length; i++) {
        if (mtn[i].properties.location.iso3166_1Alpha2 !== null) {
          x = mtn[i].properties.location.iso3166_1Alpha2;
          console.log(x);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are getting an item that doesn't have a `location` property, in which case your condition won't help prevent it. Try changing your function as below. Notice I'm using [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), the `?.` syntax, to avoid any `null` or `undefined` property.

```
function addJSON() {
  let url = "https://development.example.com/admin/mtn/json/mtn_areas.geojson";
  fetch(url)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      let mtn = data.features;
      for (var i = 0; i < mtn.length; i++) {
        if (mtn[i]?.properties?.location?.iso3166_1Alpha2) {
          x = mtn[i].properties.location.iso3166_1Alpha2;
          console.log(x);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have a question.  What is this called:  mtn[i]?.properties?.location?  How can I read more about that ? mark please?  What keyword to search. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure @spreaderman. It's called Optional chaining. I edited my answer to add a link to MDN.